# NUnit Test override Extension C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, testing, extension-methods

I have the following methods that **I cannot change**

```
static int A ( string var )
static int A ( this string var )
```

Since they are defined as static, in order to test them I thought to create public methods that call them like

```
public static int ATest ( string var )
{
   return A(var);
}
public static int ATestThis ( this string var )
{
   return A(var);
}
```

And then test them in that way

```
namespace test.NUnit
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class myFirstTest
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestOnA() {
            Assert.... // with ATest and ATestThis
        }
    }
}
```

However I obtained these two errors

```
Type 'Program' already defines a member called A with the same parameter types
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: ```I have the following methods that I cannot change``` where you have them? At same class?

Comment: They are provided by the teacher

Comment: Do you think that put them in two different class could solve the problem?

Comment: Yep, because error text means that one class cannot contain 2 methods with same name and signature. So, you need to rename one of them or put them to different classes.

Answer (score 0):

> CS0111    Type 'Program' already defines a member called 'A' with the same parameter types

This error is telling you that the compiler can differentiate the following two methods.

```
static int A ( string var )
static int A ( this string var )
```

You can solve this by changing the name or the parameter of one of those methods or by moving one of the methods to another class.

> CS0121    The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Program.A(string)' and 'Program.A(string)'

This exception is just a followup error of the first. When you call `A(var);` the compiler doesn't know which method you meant as both have the same name and the same parameters.